# Get class-level dependencies from inside Maven (jdeps)

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, jdeps

Applying `jdeps -v` to a jar lists all the class level dependencies of that jar, i.e. which of your classes uses which other class.

I would like to extract the same information during the build. Therefore, I would like to write or configure a Maven plugin that goes through all the `*.class` files generated by the build and outputs the used classes.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to take a deeper look into the [maven-jdeps-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jdeps-plugin/) which uses `jdeps` tool under the hood.

If you have any ideas for improvements don't hesitate to create a [JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MJDEPS) for it